# SWIFT: When mapping Firebase info to an object the objects are not being added to the array once returned, why?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am new to Swift/Firebase and am a bit clueless as to why cities is empty after returning objects to it. I have stepped through and a new City is being created but after it does all of the City objects, cities shows as empty. What could be causing this? The idea is to retrieve the name and image (from Firebase Storage), create a new City object from them and then have an array of these objects that I can access from another class.

```
 self.cities = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot-> City in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let cityName = data["name"] as? String ?? ""

                var cityImage: UIImage = UIImage()
                let httpsRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: (data["image"] as! String))
                httpsRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("ERROR!!! \(error)")
                    } else {
                        cityImage = UIImage(data: data!)!
                    }
                }
                
                return City(name: cityName, image: cityImage)
            }
```

Comment: My advice is to move the logic in which you obtain the UIImage outside the logic of the mapping. In this way, you can unit test that logic, ensure it works, and then try to apply it with the mapping.

Comment: The explanation provided by Doug is on point. In a nutshell, this line `return City(name:` is called before the data is returned from Firebase. The image data you're after is only valid within the closure following `httpsRef.getData`. You're going to want to probably implement a completion handler to work with asynchronous data if you attempting to retrieve multiple images

Comment: Yes, after inserting completion handlers everything worked perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`httpsRef.getData()` is asynchronous and returns immediately, before the object data is available.  The callback you provide is invoked some time later, after the data is fetched.  Meanwhile, your map closure goes on to return a new City object with the initial value of `cityImage` that you provided before the call to `getData()`.  Your code will need to be rewritten to account for the asynchronous nature of `getData()`, possibly executing in multiple stages.